# will ASP.NET core 2 WEBAPI support PROXY gateway hosting?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I am a new to *WEB API **core 2***, So I have a question here.

Will *ASP.NET WEB API **core 2*** support *PROXY gateway host*?